# AMP HTML Email Forms

Tags: amp-html, nodemailer

I just got started using the AMP Dynamic Email Framework, and I'm having a bit of trouble getting started with using it. Specifically, my problem is that, when the form is submitted on the email client (I'm using gmail), it is reloading the entire client, rather than simply receiving a response via XMLHttpRequest (XHR). So far, this is my HTML, and its pretty much copied directly from the example [here](https://ampbyexample.com/playground/#url=https%3A%2F%2Fampbyexample.com%2Fcomponents%2Famp-form%2Fsource%2F).

```
<!doctype html>
<html ⚡4email>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>amp-form</title>
    <script async src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0.js"></script>
    <!-- ## Setup -->
    <!--
      Import the library.
    -->
    <script async custom-element="amp-form" src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0/amp-form-0.1.js"></script>
    <script async custom-template="amp-mustache" src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0/amp-mustache-0.1.js"></script>
    <link rel="canonical" href="https://ampbyexample.com/components/amp-form/">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,minimum-scale=1,initial-scale=1">
    <style amp-boilerplate>body{-webkit-animation:-amp-start 8s steps(1,end) 0s 1 normal both;-moz-animation:-amp-start 8s steps(1,end) 0s 1 normal both;-ms-animation:-amp-start 8s steps(1,end) 0s 1 normal both;animation:-amp-start 8s steps(1,end) 0s 1 normal both}@-webkit-keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}@-moz-keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}@-ms-keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}@-o-keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}@keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}</style><noscript><style amp-boilerplate>body{-webkit-animation:none;-moz-animation:none;-ms-animation:none;animation:none}</style></noscript>
    <!--
      Customize success or error messages by using `amp-form-submit-success` and `amp-form-submit-error` classes.
    -->
    <style amp-custom>
        form.amp-form-submit-success [submit-success],
        form.amp-form-submit-error [submit-error]{
            margin-top: 16px;
        }
        form.amp-form-submit-success [submit-success] {
            color: green;
        }
        form.amp-form-submit-error [submit-error] {
            color: red;
        }
        form.amp-form-submit-success.hide-inputs > input {
            display: none;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>


<!-- Use `as-you-go` strategy to show validation messages as the user is interacting with the form. -->
<form method="post"
      class="p2"
      action-xhr="MY_API_ENDPOINT"
      target="_top"
      custom-validation-reporting="as-you-go">
    <p>Form Custom Validation: <code>as-you-go</code></p>
    <div class="ampstart-input inline-block relative m0 p0 mb3">
        <input type="text" class="block border-none p0 m0" id="as-you-go-name" name="name" placeholder="Name..." required pattern="\w+\s\w+">
        <span visible-when-invalid="valueMissing"
              validation-for="as-you-go-name"></span>
        <span visible-when-invalid="patternMismatch"
              validation-for="as-you-go-name">
        Please enter your first and last name separated by a space (e.g. Jane Miller)
      </span>
        <input type="email" class="block border-none p0 m0" id="as-you-go-email" name="email" placeholder="Email..." required>
        <span visible-when-invalid="valueMissing"
              validation-for="as-you-go-email"></span>
        <span visible-when-invalid="typeMismatch"
              validation-for="as-you-go-email"></span>
    </div>
    <input type="submit" value="Subscribe" class="ampstart-btn caps">
    <div submit-success>
        <template type="amp-mustache">
            Success! Thanks {{name}} for trying the <code>amp-form</code> demo! Try to insert the word "error" as a name input in the form to see how <code>amp-form</code> handles errors.
        </template>
    </div>
    <div submit-error>
        <template type="amp-mustache">
            Error! Thanks {{name}} for trying the <code>amp-form</code> demo with an error response.
        </template>
    </div>
</form>
```

Please help! I am sending the email through STMP with NodeJS using [NodeMailer](https://nodemailer.com/about/).

Thanks!

Comment: AMPHTML Email is in developer preview right now. Are you using a Google account that was whitelisted for the preview? Otherwise, Gmail currently doesn't render AMPHTML Emails.

Comment: Just so I understand correctly, does whitelisting mean that I use the Experimental Access flag inside settings? If so, then yes I do.  But if that isn't what you meant, then I would love to know more about that process!